# Does the Ensnaring Strike spell work against an Ochre Jelly?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, conditions

Does an Ensnaring Strike restrain an Ochre Jelly in 5e?

I'm also assuming the answer would apply to any other ooze. Is that right?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, it will be restrained

[*Ensnaring strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ensnaring-strike) (PHB, p. 237) has the following text:

> The next time you hit a creature with a weapon attack [...] the target must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be restrained by the magical vines until the spell ends. A Large or larger creature has advantage on this saving throw.

Since the [Ochre Jelly](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ochre-jelly) doesn't have immunity to the restrained condition, if it failed the save, it would be restrained. I imagine the confusion comes from the Amorphous feature:

> The jelly can move through a space as narrow as 1 inch wide without squeezing.

However, this only applies to the jelly while it is able to move, and since the restrained condition sets a creature's speed to 0, this would not help the ooze escape the vines.

As none of the other oozes in the *Monster Manual* have immunity to being restrained, this would apply to each of them as well. Note that the [Slithering Tracker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/slithering-tracker) from *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (p. 191) is immune to the restrained condition, so the spell would have no effect on it.

Comment: Hi legodude5000, I've made a small edit to your answer, just to turn the bolt text into a "proper header" (see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6498/35259)) and just to expand out the "Yes" to be a bit more verbose (sometimes, although not necessarily in this case, a question's title and the last thing asked in the question body can have opposite answers, so saying more than "Yes" or "No" helps to resolve any ambiguity; see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5058/35259) for more on that). Besides that, though, this is a good answer; +1

Answer (score 3):

### Rules as written, an Ochre Jelly will be restrained

> the answer would apply to any other ooze. Is that right?

Not exactly. Each monster stats block in 5e has its own condition immunities.

Ensnaring strike applies *restrained* condition:

> the target must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be restrained by the magical vines until the spell ends

An Ochre Jelly isn't immune to this condition:

> **Condition Immunities:** Blinded, Charmed, Deafened, Exhaustion, Frightened, Prone

It may also be helpful to use the filters on D&D Beyond's to [find which creatures with the ooze type are immune to the restrained condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=14&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-condition-immunity=13). It turns out that the [Slithering Tracker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/slithering-tracker) (VGtM, p. 191) is the only ooze so far that is immune to the restrained condition (thanks @V2Blast for this catch).

Comment: It may also be helpful to use the filters on D&D Beyond's to find [which creatures with the ooze type are immune to the restrained condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=14&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-condition-immunity=13). It turns out that the [Slithering Tracker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/slithering-tracker) (VGtM, p. 191) is the only ooze so far that is immune to the restrained condition.